# Unity Build Error: Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [:arcore_client:] AndroidManifest.xml:30:9-54

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

i am using ARFoundation 4.1.0 preview package and in XR plug-in management in unity project settings i have enabled the Arcore but the problem is when i build it gives me "Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [:arcore_client:] AndroidManifest.xml:30:9-54". and when i disable the Arcore it works fine but i get black screen camera.

Answer (score 10):

I have similar question with you, but I was using ARcore SDK.

This issue happens for the combination of:

- Using Android-SDK's API level 31 (or later),
- With old Gradle version(s).

> Basically, updating build-tools to 31 is not enough to support `queries` element (of manifest, added since Android 11+). Gradle needs to be updated, too.

I solved it by changing Gradle-plugin in my `assets--plugins--android--mainTemplate.gradle` file, from `3.4.0` to `3.6.0`, like:

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
}
```

you may need to check "Customer Gradle Templete" in player setting-publishing setting-build, to create this file

Answer (score 3):

i solved it by reverting back from ar foundation preview 10 4.1.0 to preview-2

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the **gradle file configuration issue**. You have to manually make some changes in the custom gradle files in **Unity 3D 2019+** versions.

1. `Go to Preferences > External Tools > Android > Gradle`, and set the custom Gradle to Gradle 5.6.4 or later. If you are already having it then skip the step.

   [image]
2. `Go to Project Settings > Player > Android tab > Publishing Settings > Build`, and select both:

   **Custom Main Gradle Template**

   **Custom Launcher Gradle Template.**

   [image]
3. Apply the following changes to both generated files:

   **Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle**

   **Assets/Plugins/Android/launcherTemplate.gradle**

   If present, remove the following comment at the top of the file:

   **// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN**

Insert the following lines at the top of the file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the Gradle version that your Unity version uses from [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html).
2. Then find the latest Gradle plugin version compatible with the Gradle version found in step one from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?authuser=1#updating-gradle).
3. In the [Publishing Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html#Publishing) section in the Player Settings, tick the `Custom Gradle Template` option. Unity then generates a default `mainTemplate.gradle` file in `Assets/Plugins/Android/` folder.
4. In the `mainTemplate.gradle` file, update the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` plugin version to the newer version found in step 2.